# How do I create a flowchart with a getch function?

Tags: c, diagram, flowchart

My program is written in C language and it basically has an I/O function to check whether the credentials entered for the username and password are correct (I used a simple if-else statement for this).

I have to add a flowchart with the program and I can't seem to wrap my head around how I would do that. How do I combine a `do`-`while` loop with a `getch()` function and an `if`-`else` statement in a flowchart? I have a `getch()` function to mask the password with an "*" / asterisk.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
  
int main()
{
    char username[15];
    char password[12];
    int i=0;
     
    printf("\nUsername: ");
    scanf("%s",username);
  
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    do
    {
        password[i]=getch();
        printf("*");
        i++;
    }
    while(password[i-1]!='\r');
    password[i-1]='\0';
     
    if( strcmp ( username,"usernamesample" ) == 0 && strcmp ( password,"password1234" ) == 0 )
    {
        printf("\nVALID!");
    }
    else
    {  
    puts("\nINVALID!"); 
      
    return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: A flowchart of what? It's unclear what the desired result is

Comment: You might want to start. show us your attempt and tell us where you stumble. Please [edit] your question for this, don't post links in comments.

Comment: Please pick a language and only add the related tag. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: I think maybe your teacher wants you to *draw* (not write code (in whatever language)) something like this? https://sipoc.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Process-Flowchart-Template-Example.png

Comment: As your credentials handling doesn't seem to be related to some flowchart you might remove that part from the question when you add your attempt for the flowchart. Nevertheless there are 2 bugs in your code: 1) `password` can never hold the correct password as it can only hold 11 characters + 0 terminator. 2) You never care about checking your input for allowed length. You should ensure that name and password are limited to the length of your buffers.

Comment: @pmg yeah create a process flowchart like that. From the input of username and password to the printing of "VALID" or "INVALID"

Comment: So, 'C' (and 'C++') tags are irrelevant

Comment: @pmg oh yeah that makes sense i edited it already thank you

Answer (score 0):

A flow chart documents the control flow in your program. The challenge is to cope with the very basic control flows operations that this kind of diagram knows.

Operations that follow sequentially are shown in boxes linked with arrows.

Conditional flows such as `if (condition) { /*then do*/ } else { /*else do/* }` use a diamond:

[image]

There is no standardized loop symbol.  So you need to show the loop using conditionals:

- `while (condition) { /*do something*/ }` looks like:

  [image]
- `do { /*do something*/ } while (condition);` looks like:

  [image]
- Finally, the `getch()` is user input:

  [image]

C conditions can call functions such as `getch()` and perform user input while evaluating the condition. The flow-chart do not allow this; you need to decompose the flow and add extra symbols before the conditional diamond. The `while` loop then requires you to loop back not just before the diamond, but before these extra symbols, so that the preparation of the conditional evaluation is performed properly.